# Delete attribute / column from simpledb

Tags: amazon-simpledb

I have a simpledb column 'Status' I want to get rid of it. How can I delete it ? I dont see any intuitive way to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SimpleDB is a schema-less database each item may have different sets of attributes. In order to remove a particular attribute from all items you're going to need the itemNames for all items containing the attribute.

If you've decided to emulate a relational table in SimpleDB (by having one domain per 'table' and uniform attributes per item) you can retrieve all itemNames by a simple select query `select itemName from domainX`.

Once you've got the itemNames for the items which contain your unwanted attribute you'll need to call [DeleteAttributes](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/SDB_API_DeleteAttributes.html) once for each item.